# Multilingual sites and Google search results, using sub-folders for language

Tags: google-search, multilingual

About three months ago we added an English version of our, previously Japanese only, site under the subfolder /en/ we've tried to follow the sometimes incomplete best practices laid out by Google by adding alternate tags to all pages that are currently translated.  The top page for instance has the following meta tags for language.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/en/">
```

While the English main page under /en/ has

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/en/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/en/">
```

Alternate languages are setup in the sitemap. (as per Google's recommendations)

It seems however that Google absolutely refuses to show the English top page in results when the user is using English at google.com if you search you'll, as of this post, get the Japanese description and a title that Google has apparently invented instead of the title and description in the meta-tags for the /en/ index page.

Does anyone have any experience with subfolders actually working to affect search results?  What are the best practices for ensuring that the correct language version of my website is displayed through Google and other search engines? And how long will it take before the new language version becomes prominent in search engine results?

NOTE: per GDav's suggestion I've removed the following tags for now as a test.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/">
<link rel="canonical" href="/en/">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdirectories aren't themselves an issue: I've worked with successfully geotargeted sites which are organised that way. Obviously, this assumes good practice in other areas, e.g. appropriately targeted content.

One possible problem I can see with your code above is use of the canonical link element. Originally [Google recommended it, but no longer do](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html), so I'd try removing that before proceeding further. A colleague of mine attended a Google Webmaster Hangout to enquire how long this code should need to take effect, and was told that it should be a matter of weeks.

That element aside, if you haven't already done so, and you're using a gTLD, setting geographic target for the Japanese subdirectory in Google Webmaster Tools is worthwhile. You *might* want to consider setting `/en/` to unspecified, too, if it's genuinely not aimed anywhere in particular.

Comment: I'll try striping the canonical from the main page and see if this as an effect.  Regarding the gTLD since the site was originally in Japanese I left all Japanese pages as they where rather than using "/ja/" where as in English we added "/en/".

Comment: Having looked at what I think is your site, I suspect the temporary redirects you're using to send people to `/en/` might be a big part of the problem. Off topic for the above question, though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm purposely not doing them for bots though, I know technically you're not supposed to treat GBot differently but also I think not taking advantage of language headers, if possible, is lazy.  I'll try taking them offline completely.

Comment: So nothing after removing the language negotiation.  Google still isn't picking the english site up after more than a month.

Comment: @AWinter As per my last comment, I suspect your problem in fact lies in conditional redirect issues, assuming that was in fact your site.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a global website with 13 language variants - all set up in exactly this was (/en/ /fr/ /pl/ etc...)

If you can show me a link to your website I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: First off I can see a couple of errors in your language rel tags:

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up url rewriting rules to 301 redirect your previous urls to example.com/ja/

I did it on some sites with no canonical at all, using only the alternate languages links, but with each page full url.

E.g.: 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/en/home-en/">
on the Japanese page

and 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="/ja/home-ja/">
on the English page

Comment: I've been debating doing this but since it will force a total re-index of the site I'm trying to gather as much information as possible before hand.